# lodash: increment integer in string

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I want to make:

**First example:**

`some_text_505` → `some_text_506`

**Second example:**

`sometext505` → `sometext506`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like the following, but by using the regex, if you have numbers anywhere else apart from the end, it won't work

```js
var myString = 'sometext506';
var myInt = parseInt(myString.replace(/\D/g,'')); // get rid of non numeric characters
var newString = myString.replace(myInt, '') + (myInt + 1);
console.log(newString)
```

**Update**

I have just found this function which seems a lot neater and will work with numbers in the middle of the string too:

```js
function getAndIncrementLastNumber(str) {
    return str.replace(/\d+$/, function(s) {
        return +s+1;
    });
}

console.log(getAndIncrementLastNumber('sometext506'))
console.log(getAndIncrementLastNumber('some_text_506'))
console.log(getAndIncrementLastNumber('some2text508'))
```